# Defining Heap Analytics events with components build by libraries?

Tags: reactjs, antd, styled-components, heap-analytics

I'm using Heap analytics to capture events. What's frustrating is that I'm using styled-components and and-design, so events will be defined like so:

[image]

As a workaround, I'm adding IDs (or data attributes) to my components like this:

[image]

However, this is where my problem lies: I'm using a component library, [Ant design](https://ant.design/) and I'm trying to add an ID or data attribute to a `Select` component:

```
import Select from 'antd/lib/select'

<div id="headcount--dropdown">
  <Select>
    {props.options}
  </Select>
</div>
```

However when I look at the event, I see something like this: [image]

Where the auto generated selector should be `#headcount--dropdown`

I'm not sure how to get the auto generated selector to ONLY show my ID or data attributes. Could someone please help?